# Ruby handle empty array which is referred to in Case condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following Ruby code:

```
case [input.deep_array_count, input[0][9].nil?, input[1][8].nil?, input[2][8].nil?]
when [2, false, true, true] then QueryType = 1
when [3, false, true, true] then QueryType = 3
else
end
```

My input array contains multiple sub-arrays. I want to extend this case statement to find out the sub array count and whether or not some conditions are true or false.

The problem is, when the input Array is "too short" it will throw an error. For example, if I have 3 sub-arrays in "input", the following check:

```
input[2][8].nil?
```

will cause the code to fail because there the sub array doesn't exist:

```
 undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

How can I get a case to execute and ignore the error caused by missing input?

Thank you for any suggestions!
Hendrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're checking for specific conditions within the sub-array (assuming it exists).

```
input[2][8].nil?
```

What about checking for the presence of the sub-array in a compound conditional in your case statement?

```
input[2].nil? || input[2][8].nil?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `try` method, like this :

```
input[2].try(:[],8).nil?
```

In fact, `x.try(method, args)` is equivalent to `x.nil? ? nil : x.method(args)`.

In your specific case,

`input[2].try(:[],8).nil?`

is equivalent to

`(input[2].nil? ? nil? : input2[2][8]).nil?`

... because `an_array[x]` is a short way to do `an_array.send(:[], x)`.